# Calculated column as Look up column in Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Can a calculated column be used as a look up column in Update list item action in SharePoint 2013 designer workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As a short answer**: **NO**, you can't use a `calculated column` as a lookup for all actions in SharePoint Designer Workflow (not only update list item action)!

`Calculated column` is a read-only column that calculated based on a specific formula that its value can't be set via SharePoint workflow or other.

So when you tried to select the field in `Set this field', you will not get the calculated column as shown with red. meanwhile, you can get its value at`To this value` as shown with green

[image]